# width: '100%' vs Dimension.get('window').width in react native

Tags: react-native, styling

I'm new to react native and css styling as a whole so sorry if the question is very basic. I want a view to take 100% of the available screen width and when i use the code below my view seems to go outside the screen boundry, though when I use Dimension.get('window').width it work just fine. can someone explain how they differ from each other. any help would be really appreciated. thanks

```
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.food_wrapper}
            onPress = {()=> this.userAction()}
        >
            <Text style = {styles.foodname}>
                {this.name}
            </Text>

            <Text style = {styles.foodprice}>
                Rs: {this.price}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );


food_wrapper:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection :'row',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    alignItems:'flex-start',
    width: '100%',//Dimensions.get('window').width,
    minHeight: 50,
    marginVertical: '1%',
    padding: '2%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(155,200,200)'
},
```

[image: when I use Dimensions.get('window').width]

[image: when I use width: '100']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand what is the basic difference from `100%` and the width you get using `dimension.get('window')`

`100%` means you want to get the container 100% width which mean if your parent container is 50px then 100% will return 50px.

the `width` from `dimension` give you a static width of your device width

so be careful to choose what to use to your component

if you want to follow the parent container then it is easier to use `100%` then `width` from `dimension` but for responsive reasons without any parent container or it is the parent itself then `width` from `dimension` will work better

Comment: My pleasure @Syed.bcc

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a wrapper view with `flexDirection: 'row'`, then style the child view (or Touchable or whatever) with `flex: 1`

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'grey' }} />
</View>
```

Or you could use `alignSelf: 'stretch'` inside a few with `flexDirection: 'column'` (which is the default for all views)

Hang in there. Learning flexbox takes some practice. Your first thought when you get stuck should be "do I need to add a wrapper view?"